# Make an item in a list view selected by default

Tags: android, listview

How do I make an item in a list view selected by default?? I know this has been answered in previous stackoverflow posts but I can't same to make this work. I have used a number of combinations specified in the forums but none work.

here is my code:

```
        // create the list view
        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        // create adapter
        TimeAdapter adapter = new TimeAdapter(getContext(), stringArray, 3);
        // set adapter to the list view
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setItemChecked(3, true);
        listView.setSelection(3);
        listView.performItemClick(listView.getSelectedView(), 3, 0);
```

my XML Layout

```
            <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:listSelector="@color/colorAccent" />
```

[update]
I tried to modify based on your suggestions in getView but still no help :( This time, a lot of rows are being highlighted instead of just one!

```
public class TimeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<String> mArrayString;
    private int mSelection;

    public TimeAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> arrayList, int selection) {
        super(context, 0);
        mArrayString = arrayList;
        mContext = context;
        mSelection = selection;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.time_item, parent, false);
        }

        String time = mArrayString.get(position);
        TextView mTimeTextView = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.time_text);
        mTimeTextView.setText(time);

        if (mSelection == position){
            listItemView.setSelected(true);
            listItemView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.
             getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        }


        return listItemView;
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mArrayString.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mArrayString.size();
    }


}
```

Comment: do the operation in `getView()` method in adapter class.  check which position you want to select.

Comment: post your adaper code

Comment: posted adapter code

Comment: i tried in getview and still no success

Comment: yourListView.setSelection(0);
yourListView.getSelectedView().setSelected(true); and also check https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/329402-how-to-select-listview-first-item-by-default/

Comment: What do you exactly mean by selected, like you want to color it ?? or make it clickable or like what ?

Comment: I want to color it

Answer (score -1):

You can try this :

```
     // create the list view
     final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
      // create adapter
     final TimeAdapter adapter = new TimeAdapter(this, stringArray, 3);
     // set adapter to the list view
      listView.setAdapter(adapter);
       listView.setSelection(3);
        listView.setItemChecked(3, false);
        listView.performItemClick(listView.getSelectedView(), 3, 0);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(ListViewDemo.this, "position is :"+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                adapter.setSelection(position);
            }
        });

   public class TimeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private static final int NOT_SELECTED = -1;
        private Context mContext;
        private ArrayList<String> mArrayString;
        private int mSelection;

        public TimeAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> arrayList, int selection) {
            super(context, 0);
            mArrayString = arrayList;
            mContext = context;
            mSelection = selection;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View listItemView = convertView;
            if (listItemView == null) {
                listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                        R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            }

            String time = mArrayString.get(position);
            TextView mTimeTextView = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            mTimeTextView.setText(time);

         /*   if (mSelection == position) {
                convertView.setSelected(true);
             mTimeTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.md_amber_800));
               mTimeTextView.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent)));
            }*/
            if (position == mSelection) {
                // your color for selected item
                listItemView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary));
            } else {
                // your color for non-selected item
                listItemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            }

            return listItemView;
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            return mArrayString.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mArrayString.size();
        }

        // if called with the same position multiple lines it works as toggle
        public void setSelection(int position) {
            if (mSelection == position) {
                mSelection = NOT_SELECTED;
            } else {
                mSelection = position;
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
```

Comment: i tried it in getview. i passed the selection in the constructor. still nothing worked :(

Comment: i have update answer as you mentioned you want to color the list selected item so  plz check.

Comment: I did what you mentioned but for some reason it is selecting a lot of rows instead of just one?!

Comment: I have updated my code according to what you mentioned above now its working fine, hope this time it will help you.